# Is the derivative of a periodic function always periodic?

Tags: derivatives, periodic-functions

> True or False :
> The derivative of a periodic functions is always periodic.

I thought it to be true , as everything about a periodic function repeats itself at regular intervals, and so should it's derivative . But , to my surprise it is given false , which suggests that it might be true most of the time but **not always** , I have given all my thoughts to finding a counter example but I just can't seem to find even one counter example .

One possibility was $\{x\}$ , which is not differentiable at every integer , and I am confused about whether I should call it periodic or not , because it's graph will be a straight line with holes at every integer , so in a sense it is periodically not defined , just like $\tan x$ wich is not defined at every odd multiple of $\pi\over 2$ but still it is said to be periodic .

Could someone please help me find a counter example and clarify about periodicity of derivative of $\{x\}$.

Thanks !

$\{x\}$ is fractional part of x .

Comment: The statement looks true to me.. even the derivative of $\{x\}$ is periodic, not existing at $x \in Z$

Comment: I would say it is true. I suppose it depends on the technical definition your book uses though, so I would look carefully at that. For example, some would not consider a constant function to be periodic (because it has no minimal period), but some would (because $c(t+T)=c(t)$ for all $t$, so $T$ is a period for $c$).

Comment: Even if we only count functions with a minimum positive period, the answer is "true". If $T$ is a positive period for $f'$ then $f'(x) = f'(x+T) = \frac{d}{dx} (f(x+T))$, so the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $f(x) - f(x+T) = f(0) - f(T)$ for all $x$. If $f(0) \neq f(T)$ we will get a contradiction: first, if $T$ is a rational multiple of the minimum positive period $P$ of $f$, the contradiction is clear. Next, if $T$ and $P$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\lvert f(x) \rvert$ will take arbitrarily large values on $[0,P]$, which is impossible by compactness.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $f$ is periodic with period $T$, then $f'$ is also periodic with period $T$, because, if $f$ is differentiable at $x$,\begin{align}f'(x+T)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+T+h)-f(x+T)}h\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\\&=f'(x).\end{align}And $\{x\}'$ *is* periodic with period $1$ (although its domain is not $\Bbb R$).

Comment: I think it is based on the usage of terms ,  at integers it is not defined , but the domain of my original function was R , as you said , "if f is differentiable at x" only then this arguement follows , but it is not differentiable at integers, so my argument that it is periodically not defined fails , as when I check it's periodicity over R (which I should) , I can not say that it is periodic as **two not-defines are not equal** . Thus derivative of $\{x\}$ is periodic only when I separately define it's domain (which I obviously haven't) , until then , it is not periodic over R .

Comment: I guess this is why it is definition based , that is , whether automatic change of domain is acceptable or not , I wrote this comment just to sure whether what I have understood is right or not ? Could you please go through it and let me know whether it is correct or not , thanks !

Comment: I do not agree. Of course, yes, it depends upon how the expression “periodic function” is defined. But the most common one is this: a function $f\colon D(\subset\Bbb R)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is periodic with period $T\ne0$ if $D+T=D$ and if $(\forall x\in D):f(x+T)=f(x)$. With this definition, $\{x\}'$ *is* periodic and its domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Got it , thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

The answer is actually "true"; at least, the derivative of any differentiable periodic functions is periodic. This is easy to prove:

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable periodic function with period $P$. Let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $g(x) = x + P$. Then $f = f \circ g$ so $f' = (f \circ g)'$. By the chain rule, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$f'(x) = (f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) = f'(x+P).$$
In other words, $f'$ is periodic with period $P$.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shortcut to what @diracdeltafunk said above.

You could **directly** apply the chain rule on $f(x)=f(x+T):$
\begin{eqnarray*}f(x)=f(x+T),~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}&\Rightarrow&f'(x)=(x+T)'\cdot f'(x+T),~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\\
 &\Rightarrow&f'(x)=f'(x+T),~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}