# Proof that $\cos(t^2)$ is not periodic

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove that $f(t) = \cos(t^2)$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is not periodic.

Suppose this function has a period $B > 0$, i.e. suppose that

$\cos (t^2) = \cos((t+B)^2)$ for every $t$.

Set $t=0$, then it follows that

$B^2 = 2k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$

But I am unable to continue further.

I tried setting $t$ equal to some other values but nothing seems to work.

How can we prove this function is not periodic?

I am looking for some sort of elementary (in some sense) proof.
Assume that for the proof we can use calculus of functions of one variable (and anything that comes before that).

Comment: Have you seen [a graph of $ y = \cos (t^2)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28t%5E2%29)? That could give you some ideas of how to show non-periodicity. EG Solve for $ 1 = \cos t^2$, which is clearly not periodic.

Comment: If $f$ is periodic, then so is $f’$. What’s the derivative?

Comment: @peter.petrov: My answer is continuation to where you left off in OP.

Answer (score 7):

If $f$ is periodic then $f'$ is periodic, as ${d\over dx}f(x+a)={df\over dx}(x+a).$ If additionally $f'$ is continuous, then $f'$ is bounded.  We have $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\cos(t^2)=-2t\sin(t^2)$$ The derivative is unbounded hence it cannot be periodic. Thus $\cos(t^2)$ is not periodic.

Comment: Uh huh…………………..

Comment: The derivative of $\tan x$ is also unbounded...

Comment: Just to add a detail: continuous, periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ must be bounded.  That's the case, because if such a function $f(x)$ has period $T$ then it has a maximum value $K$ on $[0, T]$ (by the extreme value theorem). Then any $x$ can be written as $kT + y$ for $y \in [0,T]$, and then $f(x) = f(y) \leq K$.

Comment: @user You are right.  I have added the assumption that  $f$ is continuously differentiable like $\cos(t^2)$ is.

Comment: [Derivative of periodic function is periodic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742728/is-the-derivative-of-a-periodic-function-always-periodic)

Answer (score 1):

Let us observe that the equation $$\cos(B+t) ^2=\cos t^2$$ holds if and only if $$(B+t) ^2\pm t^2=2k\pi$$ for some integer $k$ depending on $t$. In other words we have $$B^2+2tB=2k\pi$$ or $$B^2+2tB+2t^2=2k\pi$$ Now let us consider small enough positive values $t, t'$ with $t'<t$ and corresponding to these values we have two integers $k, k'$ respectively such that one of the following  cases holds (these being exhaustive)

**Case 1**: $$B^2+2tB=2k\pi, B^2+2t'B=2k'\pi$$ Subtracting these equations we get $$(t-t') B=(k-k') \pi$$ The right side is an integral multiple of $\pi$ and hence can take values only in a discrete fashion so that it is either $0$ or greater than equal to $\pi$ in absolute value. But if $B\neq 0$ the left side can take small enough positive value based on choice of numbers $t, t'$ and hence the equation can't hold unless $B=0$.

**Case 2**: $$B^2+2tB+2t^2=2k\pi,B^2+2t'B+2t'^2=2k'\pi$$ Again subtracting these equations we get $$B(t-t')+(t-t')(t+t')=(k-k')\pi$$ and the left side can be made positive and small enough while the right side can be either $0$ or greater than equal to $\pi$ in absolute value. So the equation can't hold.

**Case 3**: $$B^2+2tB+2t^2=2k\pi,B^2+2t'B=2k'\pi$$ Subtracting these equations we get $$t^2+B(t-t')=(k-k')\pi$$ and again the left side can be made to take a small enough positive value so that the equation doesn't hold.

**Case 4**: $$B^2+2tB=2k\pi,B^2+2t'B+2t'^2=2k'\pi$$ Subtracting the equations we get $$t'^2-B(t-t')=(k'-k)\pi$$ Note that the left hand side is not guaranteed to be positive and hence may be zero as well so we need a bit more analysis. Here we can keep $t$ small enough and fixed and let $t'\to t^-$. Doing this may lead us to one of the four cases and the first three cases can be handled as described earlier. But if there is a sequence of values of $t'<t$ which lands us in case 4, then we can note that left hand side tends to $t^2>0$ and the right hand side is either $0$ or greater than equal to $\pi$ in absolute value. Thus even this equation can't hold.

This shows that the function $\cos t^2$ is not a periodic function of $t$.

Comment: Your first sentence (that if and only if) is not true. E.g. $1/100$ and $-1/100$ do not differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$ but they have the same cosine. Before asking here I made a few flawed proofs myself starting with the same delusion.

Comment: @peter.petrov: thanks for catching the problem. Well one needs to handle the case $(B+t) ^2+t^2=2k\pi$ as well. Will edit the answer and fix this.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I have covered all the cases now. Do have a look at it.

Comment: I think that $\pm$ part after if and only if in the beginning is redundant as you say for some integer $k$ depending on t (let's write it $k_t$) so it suffices to take the first equation i.e. $B^2+2tB= 2\pi k_t$. Elimination of $B$ from here using $t=0,1$ shows that $\pi$ is rational, a contradiction.

Comment: @Koro: I had initially thought like that, but it appears we need to handle both $\pm$ signs. And the choice of the sign itself will depend on $t$.

Comment: I mean that the statement '$\cos ((B+t)^2)= \cos t^2\iff \exists k_t\in \mathbb Z, (B+t)^2= t^2+2\pi k_t$' is true so we can consider only + there. You may take a look at my answer as well.

Comment: The solution to $\cos x=\cos \alpha $ is given by $x=2n\pi\pm\alpha $ and the fact that $n$ is an integer doesn't help in replacing $\pm$ with just a plus or minus. @Koro

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the values of $t$ for which $\cos t^2=1$ are of the form $\sqrt{2\pi k}$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$. And the sequence $(\sqrt{2\pi k})$ is not periodic (because the difference between successive terms tends to $0$).

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a full answer, it might be enlightening to check out the graph of the function $\cos(x^{2})$ as suggested by @CalvinLin in the comments:

[image]

Comment: I checked it. Correct, this is not a proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set $t=0$, the equation that follows is $2tB + B^2 = 2\pi k$. For any non-zero $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the solutiond in $B$ will depend on $t$. But a function $f$ is periodic if there is $B \neq 0$ that does not depend on $t$ such that $f(t + B) = f(t)$ for every $t$. Therefore the function is not periodic.

Comment: Your idea is correct, but you should note that in your equation both $t, k$ are variable. The key lies in noting that $t$ is a real variable and $k$ is an integer variable and then the equation can't hold for all values of $t$. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it 'not periodic' because $t^2$ increases at an increasing rate with increasing values of $t>0$ so prior rates of change are always exceeded and never repeated?  If so, the first derivative proves that.